# How to stream web camera video with no static ip

Tags: raspbian, software-recommendation

My raspberry uses mobile data, hence it does not have static IP. I would like to stream video only to 1 client. How can I do that, without knowing the IP of the raspberry, but having a static IP on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a network service like Zerotier (https://www.zerotier.com/) to create a private network that includes only those two devices. Then the ip of the Pi will be assigned in the private network and can be static.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the ip address you can use its network name. By default it is

```
raspberrypi.local
```

If you have renamed the RasPi, e.g. to *streamserver* you have of course to use that name, for example:

```
rpi ~$ ping streamserver.local
```